# Как можно проверить наличие драйвера в системе?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Например, нужно проверить есть ли у пользователя JET 4.0 или ACE 12.0 в системе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то это OLE DB провайдеры и их поиск осуществляется с помощью `OleDbEnumerator`.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
. . .
OleDbEnumerator enumerator = new OleDbEnumerator();
DataRow[] foundRows = enumerator.GetElements().Select("SOURCES_DESCRIPTION = 'описание провайдера'");
if (foundRows.Length > 0)
{
   /*OLE DB провайдер установлен! Всё в порядке!*/
}
else
{
   /*OLE DB провайдер не установлен!*/
}
```

Как вариант, можно искать по системному имени:

```
DataRow[] foundRows = enumerator.GetElements().Select("SOURCES_NAME = 'имя провайдера'");
```

Только вот описания и системные имена провайдеров для Access я Вам с ходу назвать не смогу.